# How to use this char function with the 'populate function'?

Tags: arrays, c, function

So I have to create some random sentences using certain words from text file. The char ** populate is creating a sentence using the "*currentsize" when the size of word is less than *maxsize. However, the maxsize is only able to take limit of 5 strings. Hence, I have to use the bottom function 'doubleit'  when the words from text file is more than 5 char (since maxsize's limit is 5). But I am not sure how to implement/ add it to the populate function.

```
char ** populate(char ** words, FILE *fptr, int *currentsize, int *maxsize)
  // to store line or word from file
    char *line;
    line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *) * LIMIT);

    // reading file using fgets(buffer, limit, inputstram)
    while(fgets(line, LIMIT-1, fptr))
    {
        // if currentSize is less than maxsize then add because we can't go beyond maxsize specified in main function
        if (*currentsize < *maxsize)
        {
            // allocate memory to store the word, using constant LIMIT
            words[*currentsize] = malloc(sizeof(char *) * LIMIT);
            
            // add this line(word) to words, used strncopy to copy characters excluding \n and \0
            strncpy(words[*currentsize], line, strlen(line)-2); 
            
            // terminate the line with \0
            words[*currentsize][strlen(line)] = '\0';

            // increment currentsize
            ++*currentsize;
        }
        if(*currentsize > *maxsize){
            strncat (** temp);
        }
        
    }
            
    // free memory used to store temp line
    free(line);
    

    // return
    return words;
}

char ** doubleIt(char **arr, int *maxsize)
{
    // create a **temp, double sized array
    char ** temp = (char ** )malloc(sizeof(char *) * *maxsize * 2);
    
    // copy elements from **arr to ** temp
    for (int i = 0; i < *maxsize ; i++)
    {
        // locate memory to store string at arr[i] in temp
        temp[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * LIMIT);
        // copy arr[i] in temp[i]
        strncpy(temp[i], "  ", 1);
        temp[i][strlen(temp[i])] = '\0';
        strcpy(temp[i], arr[i]);
        // add \0 to temp[i]
        temp[i][strlen(temp[i])] = '\0';
    }
    
    // double *maxsize
    *maxsize = *maxsize * 2;
    // return new pointer to new memory location
    return temp;
}
```

I am not allowed to use realloc for this particular project.

Comment: If you're not allowed to use `realloc()`, then you will have to use `malloc()` or `calloc()` to allocate more memory, then copy the old space to the start of the new space, and consider whether to zero-initialize the new space, and finally delete the old space.  This is what `realloc()` does behind the scenes.  You should only need to reallocate the array of pointers; the strings pointed at don't need to be reallocated.

Comment: Note that `line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *) * LIMIT); while(fgets(line, LIMIT-1, fptr)) { … }` allocates 8 times as much memory as necessary on a 64-bit system (only 4 as much times if you're using a 32-bit system).  Replace `sizeof(char *)` by `sizeof(char)` — or better, remove the multiplication since `sizeof(char)` is 1, by definition.  Note that you can use `LIMIT` rather than `LIMIT - 1` in the call to `fgets()`.

Comment: Also, this code `if (*currentsize > *maxsize) { strncat (** temp); }` is just wrong; you need 3 arguments to `strncat()`.  But that function is one to avoid — it is too easy to use it incorrectly, and when you have enough information to use it correctly and safely, there are other, better, quicker alternative functions available.

Comment: What's a better way to implement "if (*currentsize > *maxsize)?